# windows 10 iot - salvage app package from device

Tags: package, windowsiot

Allthough loooking carefully to select to proper drive to create a new iot device, I erroneously selected by micro sd with my source code. Stupid me!

However I have the app still on another running device. Is their a way to copy my app package from the raspberry back to my devbox?

Comment: And that was the *only* copy? It wasn't in source control on Bitbucket or GitHub or something? Sounds like you just learned a valuable lesson the hard way... Even if you recover the app package, it may not be possible to get back to the source code.

Comment: You are right - shit happens